# How to get the character location of a XmlElement?

Tags: c#, xml, location, character

Let's say in my C# code I have retrieved a **XmlElement** (or **XElement**) from a **XmlDocument** (or **XDocument**). How do I get the **character location** of this XmlElement in the XML file?

In other words, I want to be told

```
"Your element starts on the 176th character in the text file containing the XML",
```

not

```
"Your 'book' element is the 3rd 'book' element in the whole XML document".
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible to determine the char number, but you can find line number and position inside of the line:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
var element = document.Descendants("nodeName").FirstOrDefault();
var xmlLineInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)element;
Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}, Position: {1}", xmlLineInfo.LineNumber, xmlLineInfo.LinePosition);
```

Comment: You also have to take into effect that whitespace is most likely ignored as well.  This is probably the best you can get.

Comment: @Xaisoft - no, whitespaces are not ignored.

Comment: You also **need** to set the **SetLineInfo option** for loading the document. Otherwise the line and position values are always 0. _(tested with .NET 4.7.2; maybe 9 years ago it was different)_ `var document = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);`